# select from select, performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I would like to ask, what query should be more efficient ?

```
select col1, col2 from 
    (select col1, col2 from table2) 
where col1 = 'something'
```

or

```
select col1, col2 from 
    (select col1, col2 from table2 
    where col1 = 'something') 
where col1 = 'something'
```

It seems that second query should by more efficient but in sqldeveloper first query takes less time. Why is it like that ?

Comment: both queries will fail

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: You don't have to filter by Col1 twince in your second query. Rows with Col1 = 'something' have already been filtered in the subquery.

Comment: Why do you think the 2nd query should be more efficient? You are adding another filter into the mix. And one that is filtering already filtered records. In your given example, `select col1, col2 from table2 where col1 = 'something'` would be even one less step to deal with.

Comment: @JohnConde - you edited the tags to remove `[sql-server]` and `[mysql]` but left `[oracle]`. Why did you take that choice? Looking at the questions in the OP's history it seems more likely that they are using `[mysql]` (Oracle SQL Developer can connect to MySQL, with the right JDBC jar installed).

Comment: **Please edit your question** to make it clearer. As it stands both queries are the effectively the same, and will run the same. So there is no performance enigma we can resolve. You need to post versions of **your real queries** together with supporting information such as explain plans. Also, please sort out the tagging so we know which RDBMS product you are actually using.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small example with the following tables:

```
create table tab1(col1, col2) as
select level, case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end
from dual
connect by level < 100000;

create table tab2(col1, col2) as
select level, case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end
from dual
connect by level < 100000;
```

The first query

```
select col1, col2
from (
      select col1, col2
      from tab1
     )
where col2 = 'odd';
```

has the plan:

```
----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name |
----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1 |
----------------------------------
```

and the second query

```
select col1, col2
from
    (
     select col1, col2
     from tab2
     where col2 = 'odd'
    )
where col2 = 'odd';
```

has

```
----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name |
----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB2 |
----------------------------------
```

Both the queries have the same plan.

If I add an index:

```
create index tab1_idx on tab1(col2);
create index tab2_idx on tab2(col2);
```

the queries still have the same plan:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TAB1     |
|   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TAB1_IDX |
------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TAB2     |
|   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TAB2_IDX |
------------------------------------------------
```

Please notice that simply running two queries may not be a good way to check their performance, because Oracle will probably cache the results of the first query, thus going faster in the second one.

The explain plans are useful to undersand what a query really does and how it scans tables and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Queries that are easily transformed into each other will generally be equally efficient.

Oracle does not have to run queries in the order they are written.  The Oracle optimizer can re-arrange conditions, remove parentheses, eliminate redundant conditions, and perform other query transformations just as well as most programmers.  For specific examples, Google "predicate pushing" and "view merging".

Unless there's something more to your examples, those two queries should run in the same time.

If they don't, it's most likely a testing mistake.  Measuring query performance can be tricky because of caching and server load.

If caching doens't explain it, look at the full explain plans, including the "Notes" section.  Another reason two trivially different queries run differently is because one of them may have plan management.  For example, a DBA may have specifically added a SQL profile to one query to fix something.  And changing a single space can make the query different enough to where that SQL profile no longer applies.

Comment: "it's most likely a testing mistake"*. Amen to that. Performance testing is particularly hard to do right.